# Ajax without backend script

Tags: ajax, postgresql, http

I have a simple database application in mind and I am thinking of making it browser-accessible instead of creating a standalone one.
I almost finished creating the DB schema in a **PostgreSQL** Server and I will now start developing. My first idea was using PHP or Ruby On Rails to manage the backend logic and interfacing with the DB, but since this application is fairly simple I think that I can easily implement all business and data manipulation logic with JavaScript or with the DB triggers.

So I am now wondering: is there a way to directly send the queries to a PostgreSQL Server, without server-side scripting?
More generally: can a PostgreSQL(9.3) Server receive the queries in Http requests and provide the results in Http responses?

I know this might sound stupid, and I am not looking for answers like "Use JS for presentation, PHP for logic and DB for data storage". I believe this is a lightweight solution for a very simple application, so I want  to try it if possible!

Comment: PostgreSQL is anything but a web server, so you would still need at least that to be able to receive requests and create responses. Next, security comes to mind - If you would be able to pull of a direct link between your web server and your PostgreSQL engine ... how do you prevent the array of attack vectors (like SQL injection)? How would such URLs even look? ... I truly think you *need* a programming layer in between simply to protect your data and to benefit from the security built in to a lot of adapters (like PsycoPG", or etc.) ...

Comment: "*can a PostgreSQL Server receive queries in Http requests*" - in a nutshell: not it can not. Because Postgres does not support the http protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, That is possible.

What you can do is to send it via REST API. (post, get request ).

Here are some reference for you:

1. https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest
2. https://github.com/pgrest/pgrest

Comment: These projects seem very cool, even though I was hoping for an out-of-the-box solution, or at least an official one. Anyway, it seems they are the only way to do it...

Comment: If you are not limited to RDBMS ( PostgreSQL ) then go ahead and look for CouchDB ( NoSQL ) http://couchdb.apache.org/
WIth this, you can direct query and save using REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this for more [HTTP API](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/HTTP_API)

Comment: That's just a list of requirements for such an interface. It does not exist

Comment: I've seen this page, but *This page is an early draft proposal of an extension to PostgreSQL*...

Answer (score 1):

[update!]
This idea is currently not possible (as I tought when I answered you before).

I tought it was possible after checking this node-postgres library written in javascript but it uses Node.js specific functions not present in the web browser [as stated by the library's creator himself](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/904) and [this answer at stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417289/postgresql-connection-via-javascript).

There is this package called browserify that exports a Node.js javascript file into a browser front-end ready javascript file. The problem with node-postgres + browserify is that it throw some errors during the browserification process, precisely when it tries to access libpq (an API written in C for accessing PostgreSQL).

I'm sorry I have mistaken you
Yet I still have a suggestion for you. You can try CouchDB if you really want to build a backendless/serverless application. It is natively RESTful, handles authentication and authorization at some extent, is opensource but unfortunately: NoSQL. It processes queries based on Map/Reduce paradigm and Mango query language so it's an entire different world for you to discover if you are used with SQL.

[old answer, I'm leaving it here for learning purposes]

Have you considered using a PostgreSQL driver for JavaScript? It is not RESTful, but it can connect to PostgreSQL and query it!

The library is called node-postgres and you can download it via npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Just don't forget to enable SSL connection in the PostgreSQL server and in the client to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.

An here's a tip: if you need an ACL for allowing or denying selects or inserts for specific users you can manage that through PostgreSQL [user management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/user-manag.html) and [privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-priv.html). PostgreSQL has [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html), allowing you to define which rows in a table can be selected updated and deleted for a given set of users or groups.

Comment: This looks cool. By chance, I resumed the project just a few weeks ago. I'll better look into this solution in the next days, might promote this as best answer.